# Can I use VS Code formatting feature inside bash?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

To format a code file, let's say a Javascript file or an HTML file, open it in VS Code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Can I somehow use this feature in bash?

Is it possible to use `code` and pass it the file path and the command in terminal?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting), VS Code uses [`js-beautify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) for HTML and JS formatting, so you could simply install that and use it directly in bash:

```bash
$ npm -g install js-beautify
$ js-beautify foo.js
```

Comment: In fact, I copy/pasted one of my react component files into [beautifier.io](https://beautifier.io/) (the `js-beautify` official website) and it ruined it. But from inside VS Code things worked just great. So it seems that maybe Microsoft kinda lies about it.

Comment: And it [seems](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_formatting) that their JS formatter is built-int.